# My app crashes when i try to set Stringbuffer on my TextView

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StringBuffer stringBuffer = null;
    stringBuffer.append("zain");

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textView.setText(stringBuffer);
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the error.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.StringBuffer java.lang.StringBuffer.append(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: `textView.setText(stringBuffer.toString());` try doing it.

Comment: Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.zain.stringbuffererror/com.example.zain.stringbuffererror.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.zain.stringbuffererror/.MainActivity }

Error while Launching activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
```

instead of:

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = null;
```

However, I don't see why you're using a `StringBuffer` at all. You can simply call:

```
textView.setText("zain");
```

and eliminate the `stringBuffer` variable from your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this: `StringBuffer stringBuffer = null;` with this `StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();` in order to append a data to the `StringBuffer`.

Hope it helps.